# Automatic positions in Cytoscape graph for the nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have JSON of nodes with data but no positions. I would like to automatically create the graph based on the edges and parent json without giving the positions. It does that but all the nodes are over the top of each other.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpnys1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo_test.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the preset layout, as you can see in the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/preset), it puts nodes in the positions you specify manually.

If you want to use layouts with automatic positioning, please use any other layout cytoscape.js provides (except `null` layout).

The docs provide detailed descriptions about the [core layouts](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts), but there are also layout extensions with some cool features [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions).

Comment: Great, I started using Dagre and it is working well but is it possible to decrease the space between two nodes. For example: Heading title and id in the node. Here is the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zd1eva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: In your example, choosing a nodeSep of 45 seems a little too much, after trying out some configurations, something like ``nodeSep: 10, edgeSep: 20, ...` seems better. Also, you could make the heading node a bit smaller or use the parent label as a heading (you can place that label inside of the node and with a white color?

Comment: But I need both heading one outside and one inside the node. Is that possible to have two headings?

Comment: Yes, you can use the normal label and a popper/tippy label via extension

Comment: I updated the stackblitz with more data and edges and now you can see the spacing between nodes within the parent is not consistent. For example: Name and Address has more space now. Can this be consistent in any way?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpbhbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I tried using popper/tippy label but it does not show the label inside the parent element. Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqpepx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts